# I am trying to write a grade calculator with functions in Python

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to make a grade calculator with functions. I want to check the users input so that when they put a number in it will check and see if it is between 1 and 100, but don't know how to do that. can anyone help? I also want to make it at the end so that it says for 'subject' and a score of 'number' you get a 'grade'.

here is what i have so far:

```
class_list = ['math', 'art', 'P.E.', 'science', 'english']
my_dict = {}
for idx,subject in enumerate(class_list):
  print ("What is your score for ", class_list[idx])
  my_dict[subject] = int(raw_input())
print my_dict
def assign_letter_grade(grade):
  if 93 <= grade <= 100:
    return 'A'
  elif 90 <= grade < 93:
    return 'A-'
  elif 87 <= grade < 90:
    return 'B+'
  elif 83 <= grade < 87:
    return 'B'
  elif 80 <= grade < 83:
    return 'B-'
  elif 77 <= grade < 80:
    return 'C+'
  elif 73 <= grade < 77:
    return 'C'
  elif 70 <= grade < 73:
    return 'C-'
  elif 67 <= grade < 70:
    return 'D+'
  elif 63 <= grade < 67:
    return 'D'
  elif 60<= grade < 63:
    return 'D-'
  else:
    return 'F'
```

Comment: To simply check whether a number is between 1 and 100 you can do something like `if user_input in range(1,100):`.

Comment: ["Can someone help me?" is not actually a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Please take the [tour], read [ask] and explain what specifically the problem was when you tried to write the code that does what you want.

Comment: The idiomatic comparison would be `if 1 <= user_input <= 100: ...`

Comment: @guidot [Don't use the existence of Code Review as a reason to close a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400). Evaluate the question and use a reason like; needs focus, primarily opinion-based, etc. This question would be off-topic on Code Review as it does not work as intended. Please familiarize yourself with what is [on-topic](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and our [guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
def raw_input():    
    while True:
        score = input()
        if score in [str(i) for i in range(101)]:
          return score

class_list = ['math', 'art', 'P.E.', 'science', 'english']
my_dict = {}
for idx,subject in enumerate(class_list):
  print ("What is your score for ", class_list[idx])
  my_dict[subject] = assign_letter_grade(int(raw_input()))

print( my_dict)

def assign_letter_grade(grade):
  if 93 <= grade <= 100:
    return 'A'
  elif 90 <= grade < 93:
    return 'A-'
  elif 87 <= grade < 90:
    return 'B+'
  elif 83 <= grade < 87:
    return 'B'
  elif 80 <= grade < 83:
    return 'B-'
  elif 77 <= grade < 80:
    return 'C+'
  elif 73 <= grade < 77:
    return 'C'
  elif 70 <= grade < 73:
    return 'C-'
  elif 67 <= grade < 70:
    return 'D+'
  elif 63 <= grade < 67:
    return 'D'
  elif 60<= grade < 63:
    return 'D-'
  else:
    return 'F'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `try` and `except` functions.

For example:

```
data_valid = False

score = input("What is your score?")

while data_valid == False:
    score = input("Enter your score: ")
    try:
        score = float(score)
    except:
        print("Invalid input. Please type an decimal or integer.")
        continue
    if score < 0 or score > 100:
        print("Invalid input. Score should be between 0 and 100.")
        continue
    else:
        data_valid = True
```